# How to add limited number of vehicle in my file

Tags: c

just want to add for example 5 vehicles to my file if it's more than that, the program should give a message that the registry is full.

```
void add_vehicle(){
   
    char another;
    FILE *fp;
    int n,i;
    struct vehicle info;
    do{
   
        printf("\t\t\t\t=======Add vehicle Info=======\n\n\n"); 
        fp=fopen("information.txt","a"); 
         
        printf("\n\t\t\tEnter Owner name :");
       
        scanf("%s",info.owner);
        
        printf("\n\t\t\tEnter vehicle-No :");
        scanf("%d",&info.car_no);
     
        printf("\n\t\t\tEnter age : ");
        scanf("%d",&info.age);
        
        printf("\n\t\t\tEnter vehicle type : ");
        
        scanf("%s",info.car_type);
        printf("\n\t\t\tEnter vehicle mark : ");
       
        scanf("%s",info.car_mark);
        printf("\n\t\t\tEnter registration nummber : ");
       
        scanf("%s",info.car_registration);
        
        printf("\n\t\t\t______________________________\n");
       
    if(fp==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"can't open file");
    }
    else{
        printf("\t\t\tRecord stored successfuly\n");
    }
    
    fwrite(&info, sizeof(struct vehicle), 1, fp); 
    
    fclose(fp);
    
}
```

I don't have any idea if I should use a while loop or if statement and how in that case.

Comment: You're missing the end of the `do-while` loop. What is the `while` condition?

Comment: You should open the file in binary mode since you're writing a structure, not text. After you open the file, use `ftell()` to get the current position in the file. Divide that by `sizeof(struct vehicle)` to get the number of vehicles already in the file. Subtract that from 5 to get the number that the user can add in the loop.

Comment: Your code wouldn't compile, as it contains errors (e.g. the missing ```while```condition, as mentioned by @Barmar). Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why are you reporting `Record stored successfuly` before you have actually written the data?  Until/unless `fwrite` and `fclose` return successfully, the data has not been stored.  (Even then, the data may not be on the physical media)

Comment: How can i delete a vehicle by giving a position number (1-5)? using array